# previous_changes getting lost in after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
      after_save do
        tracked_changes = self.previous_changes.select { |attribute, _| self.all_trackables.include?(attribute.to_sym) }
        puts "\e[38;5;208m#{tracked_changes}\e[0m"
      end
      after_commit do
        tracked_changes = self.previous_changes.select { |attribute, _| self.all_trackables.include?(attribute.to_sym) }
        puts "\e[38;5;206m#{tracked_changes}\e[0m"
      end
```

Output:
After Save:

```
{"name"=>[nil, "hamza"], "phone"=>[nil, "xxxxxxxxx"], "email"=>[nil, "hamza@test.com"]}
{"assignee_id"=>[nil, 3764], "client_type_id"=>[nil, 204], "classification_id"=>[nil, 2]}
{"primary_contact_id"=>[nil, 378115]}
```

After Commit:

```
{"primary_contact_id"=>[nil, 378115]}
```

The tracked changes are getting lost in after commit. I want the changes that are in `after_save` without using extra memory. Can someone tell me why this is the `previous_changes` getting lost in `after_commit`?
The only change that is being kept is the one that is on update. the insert changes are getting lost in after_commit.
I tries both after_commit and after_save.

Answer (score 0):

The way `previous_changes` works is it only keep track of those attribute changes that are changed in previous transaction. for example -

1. during insert all the items that changed its value from nil to "something" will be tracked by previous_changes with new value and its old value.
2. during update only updated items will be returned by previous_change method.
3. If nothing updated it will return {}.

This is the default behaviour of `previous_changes` on object model.

**after_save**

1. can be run during the transaction itself.
2. sometimes race around condition may occur becuase of saved record..

**after_commit**

1. This will run only after database transaction is commited successfully to db.

Comment: You are right but I want the activities in each step that (create, update) to be saved after_commit. Because if due to some reason the transaction is rolled back. The activities will be saved (if it is before or after save). I have written a job to save activities that must run in after commit. is there any way around to this. without using extra memory to save the changes at each step?